# Python - generate case insensitive REGEXP like string

Tags: python, regex, for-loop

How can I autogenerate a case insensitive REGEXP for a string that may have the case following variations:
'ENTI', 'Enti'

I got this so far but it looks clumsy,

```
entity_type = 'Enti'
prefix = 'E'
for char in entity_type[1:]:                          
    logs_prefix += '[' + char.upper() + char.lower() + ']'
print logs_prefix

>>>'E[Nn][Tt][Yy]'
```

My goal is to initially discover the list of active logs (the rotated ones will be ending with a timestamp) which start with a given case insensitive sequence, so I can

```
regexp_filters = logs_prefix + '_A.out'
command = "ssh %(user)s@%(ip)s 'cd %(source_path)s; ls -t %(regexp_filters)s'" % locals()
```

and generate different rsync expressions for a range of hosts.
Ignore the exclude, its made of several --excludes witholder, crashed '*_A.out' logs

```
sync = "rsync -e ssh -a %(remote_rsync_binary)s --compress=9 -pgtov %(excluded_expression)s %(filters_expression)s --exclude='*' %s(user)@%(ip)s:%(source_path)s%(file_filter)s %(target_path)s" % locals()
```

Minor question, how to easily enclose a string/char with other chars,
in this case:
**[char]**

**EDIT :** 
Found a cleaner solution, is there a better way?

```
for char in entity_type[1:]:
    prefix += "[%s]" % "%s%s" % (char.upper(), char.lower() )
```

**EDIT2: (improvement)**
as @eyquem wrote,

```
prefix + ''.join( "[%s%s]" % (char.upper(), char.lower() for char in entity_type[1:])
```

Comment: No.
The goal is to autodiscover the logs which respect a given pattern in a remote path(there are some variations),
generate a REGEX string and feed it to an rsync command.

Comment: Maybe you should post also the data that you have along with the expected result

Comment: @stack_zen  ``"[%s]" % "%s%s" % (char.upper(), char.lower() ) `` is ``"[%s%s]" % (char.upper(), char.lower())`` , I think

Comment: @stack_zen And your edit can be written in a better manner ``prefix + ''.join( "[%s%s]" % (char.upper(), char.lower() for char in entity_type[1:])``

Comment: @stack_zen By the way, a pattern **'E[nN][tT][iI]'** isn't the same than the pattern **'Enti|ENTI'**

Comment: Thanks @eyquem.
I've upvoted both comments, regarding the 1st, I unnecessarily left it at that form because first I've unsuccessfully tried using it like the "[%(char.upper() )s%(char.lower() )s)" % locals() 
I've edited it using your 2nd advice, thanks.

Comment: Those patterns match of course :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
reEnti = re.compile('ent[iy]',re.IGNORECASE)
```

Comment: That would do if the goal was to analyse a range of objects with Python,
I need to generate a string to be used as a REGEXP by an external command.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this (Python 2.7.1):

```
>>> def goofy_regexp(s):
      return '{}|{}'.format(s.upper(), s.title())

>>> goofy_regexp('enti')
'ENTI|Enti'
```

Here's a 2.6 version with old style string formatting:

```
>>> def goofy_regexp26(s):
    return '%s|%s' % (s.upper(), s.title())

>>> goofy_regexp26('enti')
'ENTI|Enti'
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'format'

Is that in Python 2.7/ 3.0+?

Answer (score 0):

I can't believe python doesn't actually support ignorecase in a regex.  Just passing "Ignorecase" as a flag to the regex parser is no better than doing upper() after the fact and is useless for defining a case-insenstive regex